# convert from PHP to JSON file

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel

I am a Laravel learner. What I am trying to learn now is to send a `JSON` file from a back end into the front-end, so that I will use this `JSON` file to draw a graph.

In my model, I write a function that will extract the values and time stamp `created_at`. Here is a piece of code that will return the google page speed value associated with a single website and the time stamp.then I want to use `JS` to draw the graph where the vertical value is the google page speed and the horizontal is the time stamp `created at`.

Anyone who can help me? Do I need to change the return value to an array?

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Notification;
use App\Status;

class ChartController extends Controller
{

     public  function speedHistory(){

        $o_status = Status::where('name','speed')->first();
        $o_response = $this->statuses()->where('status_id', $o_status->id)
        ->select('values AS value', 'created_at AS timestamp')->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->get();


        if($o_response){
            return response()->json($o_response);
        }
            // return an empty json array instead of false
            //return false;
        return response()->json(array());
    }
}
```

and trhe route is

Route::get('json','ChartController@speedHistory');

keeps complaining the methods is not defined. this is my model
lass Notification extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['id','website_url','email','slack_channel','check_frequency','alert_frequency','speed_frequency','active'];

```
public function statuses(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Status')->withPivot('values')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Comment: L4 `return Response::json($data_array, $status_code);` or L5 `return response()->json($data_array, $status_code);`

Comment: Can you explain the `$o_response->values` part? If I'm not mistaken the $o_reponse should be an array and you cannot call object property on an array. Try changing the $o_reponse query from `->get()` to `->first()`

Comment: @ devk : $o_response->values , u r right it is an array. a website has may have different google page speed, for instance 70,80,100 etc, it is stored in the pivot table as values, i extracted it as $o_response->values.

Answer (score 0):

To improve on my answer, you will need to return 'response()->json()' which will change the content type to json, essentially making the response a so called "JSON file".

Can you try this? I think you are trying to get values and created_at from a collection which should not work. I assume you use L5, see Danis Abols comment otherwise.

```
public function speedHistory(){
    $o_status = Status::where('name','speed')->first();
    $o_response = Notification::where('status_id', $o_status->id)
    ->select('values AS value', 'created_at AS timestamp')->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->get();

    if($o_response){
        return response()->json($o_response);
    }
// I would return an empty json array instead of false
//return false;
return response()->json(array());
}
```

**Update:** added Notification:: based on comments from op

Comment: it seems cool to be, but sorry one question though. i write your code in my model in laravel. and then i made a route for it {Route::get('json','controller@json'} . i think the Route has to go through controller. here where i gat stack? what to write in the controller so that the i can pass the data to another page and work further with JS?

Comment: You will probably want to write this method inside your controller and not your model. I dont know what your model is called but changing $this->statuses() to your model name would be needed. If your model was called History then you might do History::where('status_id', $o_status->id). Putting this method in the controller will return the json data so that you can use it with your javascript code.

Comment: i have done the same thing as u suggested. i created a controller and a rout for it. but it complains that i have a method in the model called statuses, it complained that it can find the method.  i updated my code.

Comment: In your model you would need to add something like the following

public function statuses()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\TheModelYouAreTryingToFetch');
    }

Comment: lass Notification extends Model
{
 protected $fillable = ['id','website_url','email','slack_channel','check_frequency','alert_frequency','speed_frequency','active'];

 public function statuses(){
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Status')->withPivot('values')->withTimestamps();
 }

Comment: Why do you want to get statuses? You already got Status before. Shouldn't you replace $this->statuses() with Notification::where('status_id', $o_status->id) in your controller method? I updated my answer

Comment: ohhh because the data is in the pivot table, i am fetching it from the pivot table, not from the notification table. i will try to give you a small explanation on what is going on. i have a table notification that has web urls and a status table with 2 attributes health and speed. the pivot table , besides the notification id and status id, it has values, where the response cod of the urls are saved, in this case, i wanted the speed. that is why i used this->statuses() function.

Comment: I think we are moving away from the original question. Hopefully one of these answers solved your original question. If you need further help regarding pivots I would suggest opening a new question. Giving a good description of your models would probably help. Many have given a correct answer to your original problem but you seem to have several errors with your code which are not related which may have confused many trying to help. Remember to use the laravel log to debug and you can also run ->toSql() on your query to see what it looks like. If you need more help we can talk in chat.

Comment: 1 tnx very much. I will try to follow all the suggestions again. If it still fails, I will chat you. tnx again

Answer (score 0):

In your function:

```
public function speedHistory(){

 try{ 

       $o_speed = Status::where('name','speed')->first();
       $o_response = $this->statuses()->where('status_id', $o_status->id)
    ->select('values', 'created_at')->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->get();

       if($o_response === null)
//You can use this to go in catch: "throw new Exception();" or "return false" if you want
              throw new Exception();

      // Returns a json to be consumed in ajax
      return response()->json(['status' => 1, 'code' => 200, 'message' => 'Your message', 'value' => $o_response->values, 'timestamp' => $o_response->created_at], 200);
    }catch(\Exception $e){
      return response()->json(['status' => 0, 'code' => 400, 'message' => $e->getMessage()], 400);
    }
```

In your ajax you consume this way:

```
var request = $.ajax({
// Here's your route of speedHistory
  url: "YOUR_ROUTE",
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json"
});

request.done(function(response) {
    if(response.status == '1'){
         $("#youDiv").html(response.value + ' - ' + response.timestamp);
     }
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

Comment: @Paulo Costa : it seems cool to follow your idea. i have one question though. the speedHistory function is in model and i have a route{ Route::get('json',controller@json}, i thought, is n't it the way it works in laravel? for a route to work there should be a controller? the problem now is what to write in the controller. or do i have to hove rthe speedHistory function into the controller?

Comment: You use in the route file:
    Route::get('name_route', SpeedController@speedHistory)
and your ajax url:
/name_route

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `json()` method on `response()`.

> The `json` method will automatically set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`, as well as convert the given array to JSON using the `json_encode` PHP function:

```
$array = ['data'];
return response()->json($array);
```

[Laravel Documentation (json-response)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#json-responses)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
return json_encode(array('value' => $o_response->values,'timestamp' => $o_response->created_at));
```

Comment: i think the header will still be `text/html` instead of `application/json`. using laravel's `Response` object is advisable